# Ubuntu remembers every drive ever connected and every dvd ever inserted and PCmanFM shows it in folder panel

Tags: privacy, pcmanfm

I am using PCManFM 1.2.5 as file manager on Ubuntu 18.04.2. When I go to my media folder, there I find listed the names of every external drive I ever connected and every disk I ever inserted in my dvd drive and even for my WLAN stick a separate entry for every time I connected it to the computer. How can I get Ubuntu to empty this list daily or forget about the devices as soon as they get disconnected?

Comment: How do you `mount` your partitions/devices? Are you using Lubuntu (LXDE) or Ubuntu (GNOME) or another desktop on your 18.04.2 as I haven't seen that behavior before, and cannot re-create it on my Lubuntu 18.04.2 system. Do you correctly `umount` or `eject` the devices before unplugging?  (as I always do that, and possibly missing this step that causes the `mount` directory to never be wiped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably [didn't *unmount* the drives](http://www.linuxvasanth.com/understanding-mount-and-unmount-concepts/) appropriately; this is a common misconception when people are switching from Windows. This usually results in the [mountpoints](http://www.linfo.org/mount_point.html) still being available, and shown in file managers.

Just make sure, before you remove an external drive, to hit the *unmount* or *eject* button next to the drive name in `PCManFM`, or in the drive list in the system tray.

To remove the remaining mountpoint directories,

1. make sure no external drives are currently plugged in/mounted,
2. perform this command:

   ```
   sudo rmdir /media/*
   ```

Comment: Maybe put that in your boot up?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I wouldn't recommend that; this workaround is just for cleaning up, but the default action should always be proper unmounting.